# What is REST API end point for deleting specific version of a SharePoint Document

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, spfx

I am trying to delete specific version of SharePoint document by Id.
I have retrieved all the SharePoint Document versions by REST call with below code.

```
      let URL : string = `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/Web/lists/getById('${listId}')/items(${documentId.Id})/versions`;
      this.context.spHttpClient.get(URL,SPHttpClient.configurations.v1).then(response=>{    
        return response.json();
      }).then(json=>{
        return json.value;
      })
```

What endpoint should I call to delete specific version by it's version Id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The endpoint for deleting the specific version of a file will like this:

```
https://Tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteName/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/SiteName/DocName/code.png')/versions/DeleteByLabel('1.0')
```

Need to use GetFileByServerRelativeUrl to get the file object and then use DeleteByLabel for deleting the specific version, here is a complete code demo for your reference:

```
function DeleteFileVersionByVersionLabel() {
 
    var WebServerRelativeUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl;
 
    // Provide Internal name of the library here
    var DocuentLibraryInternalName = "Document%20Library";
 
    // Provide name of the document
    var DocumentName = "test doc.docx";
 
    var ServerRelativeUrlofFile = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + WebServerRelativeUrl + "/" + DocuentLibraryInternalName + "/" + DocumentName + "')"
 
    $.ajax
        ({
            // _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl - will give absolute URL of the site where you are running the code.
            // You can replace this with other site URL where you want to apply the function
 
            // NOTE: Version Label is nothing but the version number you see in the Version History
            url: ServerRelativeUrlofFile + "/versions/DeleteByLabel('4.5')",
            type: "POST",
            headers:
        {
            // Accept header: Specifies the format for response data from the server.
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            //Content-Type header: Specifies the format of the data that the client is sending to the server
            "Content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            // IF-MATCH header: Provides a way to verify that the object being changed has not been changed since it was last retrieved.
            // "IF-MATCH":"*", will overwrite any modification in the object, since it was last retrieved.
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            //X-HTTP-Method:  The MERGE method updates only the properties of the entity , while the PUT method replaces the existing entity with a new one that you supply in the body of the POST
            "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE",
            // X-RequestDigest header: When you send a POST request, it must include the form digest value in X-RequestDigest header
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
            success: function (data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }
        });
}
```

Reference:

[Delete File Version By Version Label in SharePoint using REST API](https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/delete-file-version-by-version-label-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api)